# PHP to MySQL won't show all colums

Tags: php, mysql

My Codes :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
      $page = 'Home';
     include('inc/overall-head.php')
?>
<html>
<style>
div.post-content table td, th {
padding: 10px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}   
</style>
<body>
<div class="post-news">
    <div class="post-title">
    Home || <?php include('inc/tag.php') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
    <center>
    <table>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include ('config.inc.php');
$con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
$count = mysql_num_rows($con);
echo $count;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 

    echo "<center><table cellpadding='0' style='text-align: center'>";
    <tr>
    <td><img src='img/avatar/<?php echo $row['Author']; ?>.png'/><br/>
    <center><?php echo $row['Author']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><h4><?php  echo $row['Title'];?></h4></center><br/>
    <?php echo $row['Content'] ; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
echo "</table></center>";

?>

</table>
</center>
</div>
</div>
<?php
include('inc/sidebar.php');
include('inc/footer.php');

}

?>
```

So it only shows one column..

i.e.

It only shows one post??
Anyone can help??

*NOTE* If you think I'm dumb, maybe. I don't know much, and I use so many php, if I didn't seperate them, it would turn to be an error.

*P.S Mark Baker asked me if I could add it until the end. Here you go.

Comment: __Columns__ are things like `Author` `Title` and `Content` from the row; __rows__ are the individual collections of columns.... do you mean it only shows one `row`

Comment: @Mark Baker : What should I use then?

Comment: have you checked if you have got more than one post in the database?

Comment: @Mrcoder He echoes 3 columns: Author, Title, Content

Comment: @bansi : I did, I even add
$count = mysql_num_rows($con);
echo $count;

Comment: If you added `$count = mysql_num_rows($con); echo $count;`, what does that display?

Comment: @MarkBaker : It showed me 6. It's exactly the number of columns in my db.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the next few lines of code, as far as the end of the while loop

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Why did you delete all the code from his question when you said you were just fixing the title and tags?

Comment: Gonna add it again. :)

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Why did you add `mysqli` tag, he's using the obsolete `mysql` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you start a new `<table>` for each row, but you never close it with `</table>`. You should just have a single `<table>` that you start before the loop, and each row of the query results becomes a row in the table:

```
echo "<center><table cellpadding='0' style='text-align: center'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($con)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src='img/avatar/<?php echo $row['Author']; ?>.png'/><br/>
            <center><?php echo $row['Author']; ?></center></td>
        <td><center><h4><?php  echo $row['Title'];?></h4></center><br/>
            <?php echo $row['Content'] ; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
echo "</table></center>";
```

Comment: Shows me an error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 35

Line 35 : <tr>

I think it's very sensetive when it detects even one "<" or ">" it shows me an error.

Comment: it shouldn't be parsing that line as PHP, the line before has `?>`.

Comment: As of I put it in, nothing changed?

Comment: You were asked to show more code, but it looks like you replaced the code with a completely different version. You copied part of my answer, but still didn't put the table beginning outside the loop. Do you understand what you're doing, or are you just cutting and pasting blindly?

Comment: <table>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <?php
      include ('config.inc.php');
      $con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 
      
      

       echo "<center><table cellpadding='0' style='text-align: center'>";
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($con)) { ?>
                            <tr>

Comment: Code in comments is totally unreadable. Add it to your question. Don't replace the old code, add it as an update at the end. And please indent it nicely, and use the `{}` code markup tool in the SO editor. I'm getting tired of having to reformat your question every few minutes.

Comment: You still have `<table>` inside the loop! Don't you understand why that's wrong?

Comment: I don't know what "tested it on the end" means. Did you make your code like mine in the answer?

Comment: I maked a new PHP File.
Is this one right?
{<?php
include ('config.inc.php');
$con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 
      
      
echo "<center><table cellpadding='0' style='text-align: center'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($con)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><img src='img/avatar/<?php echo $row['Author']; ?>.png'/><br/>
<center><?php echo $row['Author']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><h4><?php  echo $row['Title'];?></h4></center><br/>
<?php echo $row['Content'] ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
echo "</table></center>";

}

?>}

Comment: What part of "code in comments is totally unreadable" did you not understand. I'm getting really tired of dealing with you, you apparently have no idea what you're doing and can't even figure out how to post in Stack Overflow properly.

Comment: And no, it's not right. How many times do I have to tell you that you have to put `<table>` BEFORE the `while` loop? Did you just learn how to program today?

Comment: It worked!
I used this :
`<?php
include ('config.inc.php');
$con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 
      
      
echo "<center><table cellpadding='0' style='text-align: center'>";
?>
<tr>
<td><img src='img/avatar/<?php echo $row['Author']; ?>.png'/><br/>
<center><?php echo $row['Author']; ?></center></td>
<td><center><h4><?php  echo $row['Title'];?></h4></center><br/>
<?php echo $row['Content'] ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
echo "</table></center>";

{
}
?> `

But it didn't add like a "splitter".

Comment: I'm going to assume that's what I said in my answer, because as I've already said twice, it's hard to read long code in comments.

Comment: So is there a way to split it?

Comment: A way to split what? The comment? That won't help. You should post code in the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: No, the posts from the db.
It should be shown like this :

We are having a private test for the game! (First Post)

_________________________________________ (Splitter)


We are now in public test!

Comment: You should accept my answer and start a new question, since this is a different issue. But I'm not going to try to answer it, because I now know that trying to work with you is too much work for me. You don't know what you're doing and need someone to do everything for you, and I'm not interested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");
// Hier you should insert it:
$count = mysql_num_rows($con);
echo $count;
```

There you can proof if there are more rows.

Answer (score -2):

Try a foreach row:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $r) {
…
}
```

---

BTW: `<center>` is deprecated.

Comment: What are you talking about? `mysql_fetch_array` only returns one row, you have to call it in a loop. If you loop over `$row`, you're looping over the columns of one row.

Comment: <?php echo $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $r) {
…
} ?>

Like that?

Comment: @Byakuran Nope. Still one row, unless you keep it in a `while` loop

Comment: @asprin : So how should I make it?